# can anyone tell me what is the functionality of parameter 'save_new' in vf page URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, parameters, button-overrides

I wanted to know about 'save_new' parameter in salesforce URL and its usage.

Answer (score 1):

*Those of you that have been hacking Salesforce URLs for a while may be aware that you used to be able to pass a save or  save_new parameter in order to have the application save the record without the person actually clicking the "Save" button. Recently Salesforce started to throw invalid session Id exceptions when trying to auto-save records via URL*

[Source](https://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2016/opportunity-values-via-apex.php)